# .htaccess password protected folder goes to 404 page

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I've stumbled upon a strange issue.
Lets say I have folder in main domain directory: /myfolder

When I try to access index of files in this folder I go to: myurl.com/myfolder
And it works without any problems.
Now when I put .htaccess with password protection in this folder like:

```
AuthUserFile /home/mywebsite/.htpasssomerandomname
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Authentication Required"
Require valid-user
```

Suddenly instead of asking me for password when I try to access myurl.com/myfolder I get 404 wordpress template page.
Below is my .htaccess in main WordPress folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any ideas what might be a problem?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I don't understand why but it seems adding below line to .htaccess inside protected folder fixed this issue:

```
ErrorDocument 401 "Authorisation Required"
```

I've found this fix online but without explanation why it actually works that way. Anyone can add explanation? It just feels like it really shouldn't be like that.

Comment: If the server throws a `401` error, your htaccess will load the message `Authorisation Required`. This message can also be replaced by a link to a (custom) page with more information about the error.

Comment: OOOOH, F\/CK 1t 4LL, THANKS MAN!, I've been suffering with it for hours..

Comment: After 3 days and over 5 hours of work, this was finally it. All this time I suspected rewrite rules and faulty logic. I even got as far as creating the "error files" for 404, 403, 500... Finally, it was actually the 401. The 401 is not stated in the cpanel gui, so I never suspected it. The cpanel logs did not help, and the 404 error masked the 401. Thank you so much. I can finally sleep in peace.