# laravel htaccess allow directory

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, cpanel

I have a password protected directory at `example.com/staging`.

If I enter `example.com/js` I get a folder listing.

But if I enter `example.com/staging`, I get a 404 error page generated by the Laravel site at `example.com` (not `example.com/staging`), rather than a password box. Why is this?

Here is my .htaccess file in the public_html folder (the home directory) at `example.com`:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php70 .php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
      Options -MultiViews
  </IfModule>

  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]

  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

  # Handle Front Controller...
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

  # Handle Authorization Header
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
  RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

</IfModule>
```

And my .htaccess file at `example.com/staging`:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Staging"
AuthUserFile "/home/example/.htpasswds/public_html/staging/passwd"
require valid-user
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38075238/htaccess-password-protected-folder-goes-to-404-page)

Add the below line to the htaccess file within the protected directory:

```
ErrorDocument 401 "Authorisation Required"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotation marks from the directory path for `AuthUserFile`, those shouldn't be there.

Your directory path looks odd too, your `.htpasswd` file shouldn't be located in the middle of the path, but should be at the end. For example:

```
AuthUserFile /this/is/your/dir/.htpasswd
```

I'm sure it is, but as an added point, you are encrypting your password correctly? Apache will not accept a password that has not been correctly encrypted. You can use this website to help with that if required: http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/

Comment: Interesting, this is just the default file generated by cpanel