# Password-protected subfolder prompts password twice then throws 404 error

Tags: php, .htaccess, .htpasswd

**My issue:**

My website consists of some files in the root folder, as well as a password-protected sub-folder, set in my htaccess. When I try to access the sub-folder it prompts me for the password, as it should. However, it prompts me for the password twice, and after entering the correct password twice, it then throws a 404 error. If I enter an incorrect password, it keeps asking for the password.

After inputting the password, I am in fact logged in, because if I try to access a specific part of that subfolder (i.e. myurl.com/subfolder/index.php), I can access it. But obviously the site shouldn't throw a 404 error first.

**What I've tried:**

I have seen that other people have a similar issue, [regarding password-protected sub-folders and 404 errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38075238/htaccess-password-protected-folder-goes-to-404-page). However, my issue is slightly different, as I actually get to input a password. Therefore the common solution of adding `ErrorDocument 401 "Authorisation Required"` has not solved the issue.

**Code:**

This is the htaccess for the root folder:

```
#Redirects to the https version of site
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

## Removes php extensions 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

#Allow password for subfolder
ErrorDocument 401 "Authorisation Required"
```

And this is the htacess for the subfolder:

```
#Password for subfolder
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile myurl/mysubfolder/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

**Any help is much appreciated!**

Comment: Start _debugging_ the issue by figuring out which requests are actually triggering the password prompt, using your browser dev tools.

Comment: Maybe this is a possible solution to your answer it worked for me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229656/password-protecting-a-directory-and-all-of-its-subfolders-using-htaccess

Comment: Check your server logs to see exactly what's calling your files.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
> ```

If you request the `/subfolder` *directory* (and once you are authenticated) the above mod_rewrite directives (in the root `.htaccess` file) will append a `.php` extension, ie. `/subfolder/.php` and result in a 404.

(Not sure why you are getting prompted twice for the password, unless this is also related to the above rewrite, or perhaps with the way the 404 is being triggered - do you have a custom 404 document defined? Do you have any other `.htaccess` directives?)

You need to either:

- Include an additional condition in the above rule to exclude directories. For example:

  ```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  ```
- Or, in the `/subfolder/.htaccess` file, disable the rewrite engine, so the mod_rewrite directives in the parent `.htaccess` file are not processed. Although this may not be desirable.

  ```
  RewriteEngine Off
  ```